# Can't not find the nested type in 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.MvxFileDownloadCache/Timer

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

There is an error with the Download cache plugin while building with the beta or alpha Xamarin build for iOS 9. Link : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/50777/build-error-mtouch-mt2001-on-os-x-el-capitan-gm-with-xamarin-alpha-release

Stuart, is this a plugin issue (plugin needs updating for ios9) or a Xamarin build issue?
Thx! Any help appreciated. Currently not able to build and deploy.

Comment: Why are you duplicating this here on SO?

Comment: Primarily because it doesn't feel like a xamarin issue. Was hoping stuart would be able to see it better here than on xamarin forums.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** Xamarin.iOS 9.0.1.20 includes a fix tor this issue.

This is an issue with the debugging information (`.mdb` file) that's created from VS2013 .pdb file on Windows (and copied to the Mac). The quick workaround are to:

- use a release build (no debugging information); or
- upgrade to VS2015 (newer `csc` compiler); or
- use XS on the Mac (which will use Mono's `mcs` compiler);

Comment: I am using Xamarin Studio (beta build which compiles with iOS 9). I tried release mode in XS but same issue.